# Session is suddenly restarted (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: 11.10, lightdm, session

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop, and from time to time the session is suddenly restarted on its own and I lose all my previous work.

This issue has occurred after different actions such as:

- sometimes when I'm using Firefox
- sometimes when I open a document
- sometimes when I'm working with Eclipse

Has anyone experienced this situation?  What should I do?

Comment: this could be a hardware issue, memory problem etc

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91066/ubuntu-11-10-64-bit-kill-session-random. I had the same problem and touchpad-indicator installed. Hopefully removing it solved my problem.